# Родительский блок не растягивается на весь экран

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Попытаюсь максимально информативно и понятно изъяснить. 
Есть, значит, первая часть сайта, где нужно фото на заднем плане. 
Когда пишешь `backround-image(`а так же `background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center;)` в `body`, то все норм, но не устраивает то, что при попытке создать новую часть сайта, элементы с новой части идут сразу после контента первой. 
Когда пытаюсь написать `background` не в `body`, а в первый блок, то она ровняется по краям контента.  
Дело в том, что с другими блоками такая же фигня. 
Как сделать, чтобы блок выводился на весь экран и оставался гибким (не в пикселях).
ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!
Вот как все должно выглядить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот как у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
body{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
}
/* Первый блок */
.container{
  background-image: url(../img/main-bg.jpg);
  backgound-size: 100%;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.container_content{
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}
/* Header */
.header{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-height: 57px;
  margin-top: 43px;
}
.logo{
  font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #005FA3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo::before{
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(../img/logo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.top-line_info{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.top-line_info-content{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top-line_info-content:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.top-line_info-content:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.top-line_menu-content{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
.top-line_menu-content:hover{
  color: #005FA3;
  transition: 0.15s;
}
.top-line_menu-content:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 68px;
}
.img-before-top-line_info-content{
  margin-right: 15px;
}
/* Первый блок основа */
main{
  margin-bottom: 13.5%;
}
.title{
  font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 66px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.container1_button{
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 19px 60px 19px 60px;
  background-color: #005FA3;
}
.slider{
  margin-top: 18%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.slider-component{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slider-component:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.slider-button{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BuhOne</title>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900|Merriweather:900&display=swap&subset=cyrillic"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container_content">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="logo">BuhOne</div>
                <div class="top-line">
                    <div class="info-and-menu">
                        <nav class="top-line_info">
                            <img src="img/phone.svg" alt="" class="img-before-top-line_info-content">
                            <a href="tel: +71112223344" class="top-line_info-content">8 (111) 222-33-44</a>
                            <img src="img/clock.svg" alt="" class="img-before-top-line_info-content">
                            <a href="#" class="top-line_info-content">Пн-Пт 10:00-18:00</a>
                            <img src="img/email.svg" alt="" class="img-before-top-line_info-content">
                            <a href="mailto: order@buhone.ru" class="top-line_info-content">order@buhone.ru</a>
                            <img src="img/location.svg" alt="" class="img-before-top-line_info-content">
                            <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/RSJNhwPEFN22Sgxd7" target="_blank"
                                class="top-line_info-content">Невский пр. 130</a>
                        </nav>
                        <nav class="top-line_menu">
                            <a href="#" class="top-line_menu-content">главная</a>
                            <a href="#" class="top-line_menu-content">услуги</a>
                            <a href="#" class="top-line_menu-content">кейсы</a>
                            <a href="#" class="top-line_menu-content">о компании</a>
                            <a href="#" class="top-line_menu-content">контакты</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main>
                <h1 class="title">Бухгалтерские услуги<br>
                    в Санкт-Петербурге</h1>
                <a href="#" class="container1_button">Читать подробнее</a>
                <div class="slider">
                    <div class="slider-components">
                        <a href="#" class="slider-component">
                            <img src="img/slider-active.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="slider-component">
                            <img src="img/slider.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="slider-component">
                            <img src="img/slider.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="slider-component">
                            <img src="img/slider.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider-buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="slider-button">
                            <img src="img/slider-button-prev.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="slider-button">
                            <img src="img/slider-button-next.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: что. Картинка через css подключена

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду?